# How to change NSOutlineView disclosure triangle button color (say red)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

I'm using a cell based NSOutlineView.

How can I change the color of the disclosure triangle button?

Comment: not view-based NSOutlineView

Comment: this author modified the question! He asked about view based